# Getting inner tag text whilst using a filter in BeautifulSoup

Tags: beautifulsoup

I have:

```
... html
<div id="price">$199.00</div>
... html
```

How do I get the $199.00 text. Using

```
soup.findAll("div",id="price",text=True)
```

does not work as I get all the innet text from the whole document.

Answer (score 1):

Find `div` tag, and use `text` attribute to get text inside the tag.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>>
>>> html = '''
... <html>
...     <body>
...         <div id="price">$199.00</div>
...     </body>
... </html>
... '''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>>> soup.find('div', id='price').text
u'$199.00'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are SO close to make it work.

(1) How to search and locate the tag that you are interested:

Let's take a look at how to use `find_all` function:

`find_all(self, name=None, attrs={}, recursive=True, text=None, limit=None, **kwargs):...`

`name="div":`The `name` attribute will contains the tag name

`attrs={"id":"price"}`: The `attrs` is a **dictionary** who contains the attribute

`recursive`: a flag whether dive into its children or not.

`text`: could be used along with regular expressions to search for tags which contains certain text

`limit`: is a flag to choose how many you want to return `limit=1` make `find_all` the same as `find`

In your case, here are a list of commands to locate the tags playing with different flags:

```
>> # in case you have multiple interesting DIVs I am using find_all here
>> html = '''<html><body><div id="price">$199.00</div><div id="price">$205.00</div></body></html>'''
>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
>> print soup.find_all(attrs={"id":"price"})
[<div id="price">$199.00</div>, <div id="price">$205.00</div>]
>> # This is a bit funky but sometime using text is extremely helpful
>> # because text is actually what human will see so it is more reliable
>> import re
>> tags = [text.parent for text in soup.find_all(text=re.compile('\$'))]
>> print tags
[<div id="price">$199.00</div>, <div id="price">$205.00</div>]
```

There are many different ways to locate your elements and you just need to ask yourself, what will be the most reliable way to locate a element.

More Information about BS4 Find, [click here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#kinds-of-filters).

(2) How to get the text of a tag:

`tag.text` will return unicode and you can convert to string type by using `tag.text.encode('utf-8')`
`tag.string` will also work.